# Prove that for each real number $r$ we can find an $n \times n$ square matrix $A$ with real entries such that determinant of $A$ is $r$.

Tags: determinant

I have proved that for each positive real number we can find an $n \times n$ diagonal matrix with each diagonal entries $r^{1/n}$ such $\det A=r.$ But how to prove for negative real numbers?

Comment: Just use $|r|^{1/n}$ and change the sign of one diagonal entry.

Comment: Concerning your title question: even easier is to take the diagonal matrix $(1,1,1,\ldots, r)$. No need to take $n$-th roots.